# ByteBuffer views

Tags: java, nio

Do you know of any implementation of java.nio.ByteBuffer that wraps an array of ByteBuffer instances making them look like a single instance without copying the bytes into a new buffer?

Comment: `ByteBuffer` (`Buffer`) is fix-sized. It is impossible to make something like "concatenation". What do you really want to do?

Comment: I am optimising some low level code that relies on ByteBuffers and it would be good to reduce the number of byte copies that occur. Naturally copying the bytes between byte buffers is simple, but as nio frameworks have discovered; doing that for a large volume of bytes over and over does build up.

Comment: Why not create a large `ByteBuffer` at once? Or just use arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No implementation exists in java.nio, but almost all channels implement `GatheringByteChannel` and `ScatteringByteChannel` which can read and write to arrays of ByteBuffers directly.

[`GatheringByteChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/GatheringByteChannel.html):

> `long write(ByteBuffer[] srcs)`
>
> Writes a sequence of bytes to this channel from the given buffers.

and [`ScatteringByteChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ScatteringByteChannel.html):

> long `read(ByteBuffer[] dsts)`
>
> Reads a sequence of bytes from this channel into the given buffers.

There are also partial versions of the above methods, see the links above.

The point of NIO is to have as low overhead as possible, and this way of doing it (as opposed to having a separate object wrap the buffers) doesn't incur more overhead than a simple array. I think yours is the intended use case for this and their implementation.

Comment: The closest that I am aware of is a class called Bytes within Netty, sadly they do not extend ByteBuffer to achieve it though.  Channel is the wrong class for me, I am wanting to pass this through a library that requires ByteBuffer (not Channel). I have already solved this by copying the bytes, but as a lot of bytes will be flowing through this system the less byte copying that occurs the better.  Thank you for your thoughts though.

Comment: Why don't you fork the library and extend the methods to allow an array of `ByteBuffer`s instead of just a single `ByteBuffer`? I'm guessing the underlying `Channels` that are reading and writing will support the operations above, and you wouldn't have to change more than a few lines to get it to work.

Comment: That is an interesting idea, thank you. I had not considered it. My gut instinct is that it would take me more time to do that, than just to wrap ByteBuffer myself. But I will spike it and see where it leads. If they do have underlying code as you expect then I may just get lucky.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one in standard Java API.
Grizzly NIO framework have a CompositeBuffer, but is uses it's own buffer as wrapper:

```
import org.glassfish.grizzly.Buffer;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.memory.BuffersBuffer;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.memory.CompositeBuffer;    

....

ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ....;
HeapMemoryManager mm = new HeapMemoryManager();
CompositeBuffer buffer = BuffersBuffer.create();
Buffer b = mm.wrap(byteBuffer);
buffer.append(b);
```